# How to add numbers in your list, incrementally, while also being sorted from lowest to highest value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I'm trying to write code to firstly, order numbers from lowest to highest (e.g. 1, 3, 2, 4, 5 to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5). Secondly, I would like to incrementally add the numbers in the list.
eg.

```
1
3
6
10
15
```

I've already tried using the `sum` function, then the `sorted` function, but I was wondering if I can write them neatly in a code to just get everything worked out.

```
Addition = [1, 13, 166, 3, 80, 6, 40]
print(sorted(Addition))
```

I was able to get the numbers sorted horizontally, but I wasn't able to get the numbers added vertically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) with `sorted`:

```
import itertools

mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
result = list(itertools.accumulate(sorted(mylist)))
# result: [1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

The default action is `operator.add`, but you can customize it. For example, you can do running product instead of running sum if you needed it:

```
import itertools
import operator

mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
result = list(itertools.accumulate(sorted(mylist), operator.mul))
# result: [1, 2, 6, 24, 120]
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, you need a `cumulative addition`. You can code a simple one using a simple loop and `yield` the results on the go

```
def cumulative_add(array):
    total = 0
    for item in array:
        total += item
        yield total


>>> list(cumulative_add([1,2,3,4,5]))
[1, 3, 6, 10, 15]
```

---

Depending on your goals, you may also wish to use a library, such as `pandas`, that has cumulative sum already written for you.

For example,

```
>>> s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> s.cumsum()

0     1
1     3
2     6
3    10
4    15
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything to "order numbers from lowest to highest".

Comment: @martineau I assumed OP already solved this problem since he/she used `sorted` :)

Comment: I'm not sure that assumption is true. The OP should feel free to pipe in and clarify that aspect of their question...

Comment: Why wouldn't my assumption be true? Clearly there is not fundamental reason for you to think that, and the other answer just repeated OP's `sorted`.